# Increase load-out-page speed

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, seo, plugin-jetpack

I am pretty new to Wordpress and the SEO part of webdevelopment, but i want to learn. So I have trues to make my site faster, by making the images (thumbnails) smaller, and bundled the CSS and JS. The "load-out-page" went from 9,6mb to 6,1. And i have reduced the site load time by roughly 1sec - wich i feel is a great start.

But, it is still very slow. I have used the "most popular" wordpress-theme: Avada, do that should not be the problem. I have Jetpack installed for image optimalization.

I have used: https://tools.pingdom.com/#!/wM4uT/bansunen.no 
For my speedtest (it caches, so if i run my site a second time, i like the result..)

The site i am trying to improve is this: www.basunen.no

If any of You got some pointers, i would love it. Kinda stuck with what i got at the moment.

Maybe i should rebuild the whole thing?

Comment: You could install a [caching](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/cache/) plugin.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer! I have wp super cache installed and activated (and enabled) - so i dont think its that :/

Comment: I think you're spelling the website wrong... Is it not http://www.basunen.no/ ?

Comment: Moreso, following the suggestions in the performance insights of the speedtest will definitely reduce the latency of your website. You can also check [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/).

Comment: Yup thats a Good point. I googled the first "minimize request size" , but it Was Said that it was a "normal"Wordpress bug. "Leverage browser caching": the images there is the ones om the top banner om the homescreen, so i think it is because of the animated galleries that they dont get cached, maybe that is what is doing it? "Remove query strings from static resources": i am not sure how i should go ahead and Fix this. Any idea?

Comment: The _query strings_ were added by the plugin you used to regenerate thumbnails for your images. You can try disabling it, clear the cache, and run the test again.

Comment: From the PageSpeed Tools, it said that i should use gzip on my .js files, and that it would minify it by 2,1mb! That, i think, will help alot!

Comment: Or is that considered bad practice maybe?

Comment: IMHO, if it works for you, I don't see it as bad practice. Is there a group that regulates "best" and "bad" practices ?

Comment: Haha probably not, as long as google likes it, and get me high on their page i am happy with it

Answer (score 0):

I tried 5 pages on your site these took 20 to 30 seconds to load. If I visited the page again even in a *different browser* (with no local cache of the page) the time reduced to sub 2 seconds. Possibly due to these pages having no/expired cache on first visit, resulting in WPSC caching them prior to 2nd visit. **This would indicate that your main issue is NOT with page/image size/minification etc BUT with slow building of your page due to theme/plugins/your code.**

Your page size is also large and is a front end issue - see Visual Composer below.

It appears [your site is using](https://builtwith.com/basunen.no) Visual Composer and Slider Revolution.  You are probably using Visual Composer with your theme. [This SO Answer showed VC TRIPPLED the time taken to load a page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46843361/948658) and increased page size from 713KB to 4.32MB!!! The same answer also identified that if Revolution Slider is activated (whether used or not) slows page load. It looks like I am blaming plugins but I suspect these were part of your Avada package. Other theme bloat may account for more load delay.

I suggest you test what difference another theme without non-standard framework/builder makes to speed. Unfortunately, this may be difficult and may need you to re-install plugins. I learnt to my cost, commercial providers sometimes include their own "proprietary" theme frameworks/builders that make it difficult to switch to a standard WP theme and effectively lock you in to only using their software.

**Solutions:** Set WP Super Cache to preload cache. Stop using Visual Composer, Slider and other performance degrading plugins. Change your theme. Ensure your server uses PHP 7 (this will speed up page build over PHP 5).

This [review of Avada](https://www.wpcrafter.com/review/avada/) also mentions bloat and (lack of) speed.